# Does OpenTSDB support modifying data?

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

Went through the docs. Did not find much info about this but :

1. Does OpenTSDB over Hbase support modifying values? ( I know it does not make much sense as it is usually used for monitoring )
2. Does it support adding a new tag to an existing metric value?

I need to do some analysis and modification on my time series data stored in OpenTSDB.Wanted to know if OpenTSDB provides a functionality to achieve that. Something like labelling a data point "useless" , so that next time i query data and i get the datapoint , I can easily filter it checking either tag or value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have finally decided to do is :

1. Analyse and classify the point as useless or useful.
2. Retrieve the point with it's TSUID
3. Use the api/annotation end point to add a local annotation to it using the TSUID

Answer (score 1):

This link provides a good explanation of how opentsdb version 2.3 handles data modifications.  My understanding is that 2.4 is similar.

```
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing/index.html#duplicate-data-points
```

In short: it depends on the data type of each write for that point and whether compactions have occurred.  If the data type is same (including # bytes) and there has not been a compaction then it will work.  If there has been a compaction it will not work. If data type is different then it will not work.   Setting tsd.storage.fix_duplicates to true will allow the above scenarios to follow a last write win strategy.

Quoting the relevant section

> Writing data points in OpenTSDB is generally idempotent within an hour of the original write. This means you can write the value 42 at timestamp 1356998400 and then write 42 again for the same time and nothing bad will happen. However if you have compactions enabled to reduce storage consumption and write the same data point after the row of data has been compacted, an exception may be returned when you query over that row. If you attempt to write two different values with the same timestamp, a duplicate data point exception may be thrown during query time. This is due to a difference in encoding integers on 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes and floating point numbers. If the first value was an integer and the second a floating point, the duplicate error will always be thrown. However if both values were floats or they were both integers that could be encoded on the same length, then the original value may be overwritten if a compaction has not occurred on the row.
>
> In most situations, if a duplicate data point is written it is usually an indication that something went wrong with the data source such as a process restarting unexpectedly or a bug in a script. OpenTSDB will fail "safe" by throwing an exception when you query over a row with one or more duplicates so you can down the issue.
>
> With OpenTSDB 2.1 you can enable last-write-wins by setting the tsd.storage.fix_duplicates configuration value to true. With this flag enabled, at query time, the most recent value recorded will be returned instead of throwing an exception. A warning will also be written to the log file noting a duplicate was found. If compaction is also enabled, then the original compacted value will be overwritten with the latest value.

For you second question a metric can have one or more tag k/v's associated with it.  Thus a metric can have several common or disjoint tagk spaces along with associated tagv's.